# How can I get the data object by the combined query, findAll?

Tags: database, typescript, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have a request:

```
getData = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    try {
      const data = await FirstModel.findOne({
        where: { id: req.params.id },
        include: [
          {
            model: SecondModel,
            as: 'secondModel',
          },
          {
            model: ThirdModel,
            as: 'thirdModel',
          }
        ],
      });
      res.json(data);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
      return res.status(500).json({ error: err.message });
    }
  }
```

I need to get one more data for the fourth model in the data object.
Example:

```
data.fourthModel = FourthModel.findAll();
```

But with such a request, I get the error: `Property 'fourthModel' does not exist on type 'FirstModel'.`

Additionally, I tried to implement one more include, but the fourth model has no connection with the first.

At the output, I would like to receive an object:

```
{
  id: 1,
  secondModel: {},
  thirdModel: {},
  fourthModel : {}
}
```

Grateful for any help!

Comment: Is the first model associated to the fourth model? Is it related to any of the other tables or would you like just add it to the results?

Comment: @doublesharp, first model don't associated to the fourth model. I would like add fourthModel in result. Сan i expand the request? Unfortunately, on the Internet, as well as in the documentation, I did not find the answer to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the Models are not related, you will need to resolve the results for each query separately. You can do this concurrently using `Promise.all()`. Use `Model.findByPk(id, options)` when searching for a row by the primary key.

```js
getData = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  try {
    // Get the firstModel (including the secondModel and thirdModel)
    // and the fourthModel(s) concurrently, note the fourthModels name
    // it will return an array of results using findAll()
    const [ firstModel, fourthModels ] = await Promise.all([
      // create a promise for firstModel linked to the second and third
      FirstModel.findByPk(req.params.id, {
        include: [
          {
            model: SecondModel,
            as: 'secondModel',
          },
          {
            model: ThirdModel,
            as: 'thirdModel',
          },
        ],
      }),
      // create a promise for fourthModel query
      FourthModel.findall(),
    ]);
    // destructure the properties you want from the firstModel
    const { id, secondModel, thirdModel } = firstModel;
    // create a data object
    const data = {
      id, secondModel, thirdModel, fourthModels,
    };
    // send it off
    return res.json(data);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return res.status(500).json({ error: err.message });
  }
};
```